# Can a boy propose to a girl even if he doesn't know if she likes him?

Tags: nikah

My question is: What does Islam say about proposing to a girl for marriage, even if the boy has not confirmed that the girl likes him? As in, the feeling may only be one-sided.

So can I have some fruitful answer from Qur'an, hadith and sunnah.

Comment: How rich are you?

Comment: Yes, flap the money in the air first.  Islamically, a girl has thr right to accept or reject anyone she wishes.  Feelings are human nature but dont compel people into marriage.

Answer (score 1):

When you propose, it is her choice to accept or not, so make the proposal and find out.

Is it better to know than not to know? Do you want to know whether she likes you or not? In Quran Allah (swt) says:

> 39:9] ...Say: Are those equal, those who know and those who do not know? It is those who are endued with understanding that remember

All of that aside, in Islam, the first quality of a woman you should look at is "taqwa", this is from authentic Ahadith (Bukhari and Muslim). Then comes the rest.

So if you think she has Taqwa, and want to marry her for that reason, then make the proposal and find out, as Allah (swt) suggests, it is better to know, because knowledge leads you to understanding.

Remember, Allah (swt) knows what is best for you. Even if she says no to your proposal, Allah (swt) is saving you from a relationship that is not best for you, nor for her. When you get that, then you understand, and get closer to Allah (swt), remembering his favors.